# using classes and managing memory in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a question about using classes and memory usage.
I am trying to learn to use classes more.

```
dim test as class1
for i as integer = 0 to 10
test = new class1
test.attribute = i
next
```

Would above code leave me with multiple instances of the class "class1"?
i so, how do i destroy the class before setting the new one?
or does setting "test = new class1" destroy the previous one?

i have tried figuring from memory usage but i cant.

the class is not disposable so i cant do

```
for i as integer = 0 to 10
using test as new class1
test.attribute = i
end using
next
```

Comment: You are overwriting the values of the variable which is not the object but the reference to it. The previous object is ready to be garbage collected since it's not referenced anymore. You don't need to dispose it since it doesn't contain unmanaged resources. So actually the first code is absolutely fine apart from the fact that you're not doing anything with the objects. If you added them to a list they would still be referenced, therefore remain untouched by the garbage collector.

Comment: Ok so if i define a list off he class and then in the loop i add them to the list i would get many instances of the class? if for example i am creating a large json/xml file with ~1.000 instances of the object say its an array of movies for example. should i do "dim movielist as new list(of movies)" and add all 1.000 instances of my movies class to it before i serialize it or will that cause insane amount of memory to be used? how would be a better way to do it?   i am currently creating a json file with an array containing 20.000 instances of my class...

Comment: 1000 objects don't need an _insane amount of memory_. Dont (premature-)optimize code that doesn't need optimization.

Answer (score 0):

No. That code will not leave you with multiple instances of class1. Each time you create a new instance with

```
test = New class1
```

the old instance goes out of scope and its memory will be recovered by the Garbage Collector sooner or later (sooner if the memory is needed for something else).

Note that there is a special case where class1 owns any unmanaged resources and implements the Dispose method. In that case, you should call Dispose on the object when you have finished with it.